# Shortest distance/path between household addresses

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

If you wanted to know the shortest distance/path between two household addresses, which data structure(s) would you use to return the answer efficiently?

Say you are considering the set of all households in the United States (~100 million).

I am struggling to come up with a practical data structure considering the input size is so big.  Dijkstra's seems too inefficient, but I'm guessing there is a way to preprocess the paths to make such a query possible.  I'm just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm or something very similar it probably is the basis, although you can expect that it's highly optimized. If you put high weights on residential streets and reduce the weight as the roads' capacities increase, you narrow the search space pretty quickly.

You can also expect that there are pre-computed routes between major cities. So if you're in Miami and you want to get to Los Angeles, most of the route is pre-computed. You just need to figure out how to get from the house in Miami to the nearest highway interchange, and from the highway in Los Angeles to the destination.

Consider that the number of ZIP codes is less than 100,000, so it's not unthinkable to have a table that has pre-computed routes from every ZIP code to every other ZIP code. We're only talking 10 billion routes. Stored naively, that'd be a fair amount of data, but it's highly compressible. Consider, for example, if your ZIP code database just contained the route to the nearest major highway. Once you're on the major highways, the amount of data just isn't that large.

Although all of the roads are connected, it's not like you'd treat it as one huge graph. Rather, you have a bunch of smaller graphs--clusters--and you compute the routes between clusters. You'd also have clusters within clusters until the data gets to a manageable size.

At least, that's how I'd go about solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[The A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm) may be used here.

It's essentially an extension of Dijkstra's algorithm, where you add a 'heuristic' to each node's value, which is the estimated distance to the destination.

In this specific case, assuming you have access to the coordinates of each house, you can determine the straight-line distance to the destination as the heuristic.

Visualization:

[image]

Beyond this, Jim's suggestions are also good.